# Testing a REST Logging Web Service using C#

Tags: c#, rest, testing

I've created a pretty basic REST Web Service in VS2012 using C#. The approach I've taken is seen below in one example:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "OpenSession/{key}/{source_userid}/{source_id}/{source_version}/{source_ip}")]
string OpenSession(string key, string source_userid, string source_id, string source_version, string source_ip);
```

The code works just fine and the service is up and running. I get responses, the tokens are handed out, etc. I figured wrapping the data in the URL was just fine as the service is built for logging, so in the end, calls would be (for example):

www.service.site/service.svc/2/5/12/HELLO

(BTW if there's a better way to do this while keeping it a REST service please let me know)

The problem I have is... how do I test this properly? I need to simulate 1,000 concurrent hits to this service and have built a custom C# Windows Application to do this, but I'm encountering a number of problems.

First, I have no idea how to use HttpWebRequest and the stream readers/writers to send/receive data properly in a manageable format. I see The requests have GET and PUT methods, etc. but I honestly can't seem to make heads or tails of separating the post data vs. the URL information. AFAIK I'm not really posting any data as all my data is embedded in the URL request itself; is this correct?

Also, I have no idea what "content type" to set the HttpWebRequest to in order to be compatible with my Operation Contract (I can see the enumeration of JSON but what's the "text" supposed to be?)

And on top of that, HttpWebRequest is monstrously slow. When I open a URL directly to the service (e.g. "http://localhost:51849/Scribe.svc"), it's fast, but the second I try to call a method (e.g. ""http://localhost:51849/Scribe.svc/GetStatus"), I get a 1.5-2 second delay (and I've done all the proxy fixes to ensure it's as fast as possible).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/OpenSession/2/5/12/Hello` looks very *un-REST-ful* as a URL.  You may want to take some time to read the Fielding Dissertation, especially sec 5.2.1:  http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm  I know that stuff can be dry, but it's good to read to get some background on the intent of REST.  REST is not simply "SOAP with fewer rules" or "Web services without XML Schema."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are aware of this utility:
[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/soapUI-in-the-news/using-soapui-for-testing-aspnet-soap-web-services.html)

You can use it to reference your service and generate the requests to test your service.

The installation is pretty straightforward. After installed, you have to click on file/new SoapUI Project.
Then, in the popup window, you fill in the "Initial WSDL/WADL:" field with your service's wsdl, like this:

```
http://localhost:51849/Scribe.svc?wsdl
```

It'll generate the client to correctly do the calls to your service.
Using soap ui you can even test doing a bunch of calls to stress up your service.
This is a good way to test your services.

> AFAIK I'm not really posting any data as all my data is embedded in the URL request itself; is this correct?

Yes. That's how a GET request works. The data is passed on your url. You should only use GET requests when not changing the state of the data on the server, otherwise you should use post.

PUT methods you'll use when you want to create/update the data on the server.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using some performance tool.
There are plenty and them, should be easy to find one suitable for your pourpose.
Jmeter could be a good option.

This is a [**guide**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfNn9OuuEyU) that show how to use Jmeter to test a REST Web Service.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses! I actually have the testing system working now and can slam my service with thousands of timer-controlled sessions. The key to getting around the PUT request issue was to use empty settings:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "PUT";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.ContentLength = 0;
```

I did look at those tools, but for my specific needs, I found writing a custom timer-controlled app was the best approach.

I'm not sure if the delay is still problematic, or possibly even linked to the debug state. once I publish the service to Azure and test it remotely, I'll get a better idea if there's any latency issues with connectivity which are service based...